# Specific question about investment returns that needs someone smart to answer it!

Tags: calculus, finance

OK, so I'm trying to work out the answer to a very specific question and for me it's complex maths. I'm sure for you mathematicians out there it's fairly everyday. If anyone can help I'd be very grateful:

I start with $200,000 and want it to last exactly 15 years whilst making equal drawdowns each year. The funds continue to make 5% returns each year during drawdown. What is the exact equal annual drawdown so the pot is at zero at the end of year 15 taking into account the continue capital returns of 5%?

I'd be interested in the answer and also an idiots guide to how it's calculated!

Many thanks.

Comment: Why not try it for 2 years, then 3, 4, and 5 years until you spot the pattern?

Answer (score 3):

Deposit of $a_0$ must fund a stream of withdrawals $d$ in the end of year $i\in [1,N]$  whose present value is $d(1+r)^{-i}$. Summing that stream in present terms we get:
$$a_0=d(1-r)^{-1}\frac {1-(1+r)^{-N}}{1-(1+r)^{-1}}$$ hence
$$d=\frac {a_0r} {1-(1+r)^{-N}}\approx \frac {a_0r}{1-e^{-Nr}}$$
which tells you by how much you can increase your withdrawal compared to forever lasting annuity (when $N=\infty$ and withdrawals are $a_0r$). The last approximation is an exact answer if interest accumulation and withdrawals are done continuously.

Comment: @martin Interest rate, of course.

Comment: $r=.05$ would be my guess.

Comment: @martin Gotta round down to integer cents ;).

Comment: Wow this is quite amazing! Way beyond my brain power but I'm extremely grateful and fascinated by the response. So the answer is a $19268 annual withdrawal would completely deplete the fund after 15 years subject to a continued annual interest rate of 5%?

Comment: @Sam you might have a few bucks left over depending on how the bank rounds their interest payments. Shoot for $19268.44$ to have a negligible amount left over. Of course if you want continuous withdrawal (not just in the end of the year) (and if the interest is compounded continuously as well), you can withdraw at the rate of only $18952.55$ dollars per year.

Comment: @Sam Which works out to $51.92$ per day in the end of the day for daily withdrawals.

Answer (score 0):

While you're doing this, suppose your friend has an account that starts with 
a certain amount $A$, but makes no withdrawals.  At the rate of $5 \%$ per year, the friend's account will grow to $1.05^{15} A$ in those $15$ years while yours is dwindling to $0$.  Now let's say your withdrawal happens to be just enough to cover the interest on the two accounts together.  Then the 
total of the two accounts will stay constant.  It starts at $200,000 + A$ and ends with $0 + 1.05^{15} A = 2.078928179 A $.  Therefore $200,000 + A = 2.078928179 A$, which we solve to get $A = 185,369.15$.

The yearly interest on $200,000 + A = \$385,369.15$ is $.05 \times 385,369.15 = \$ 19,268.46$.
So that's your yearly drawdown.

Comment: This would need some tweaking for perpetual annuities.